# Specify row in TableView

Tags: qml, qt5

How I can change background color to red for row if row had timeToReply>15. I can't get timeToReply in rowDelegate. How I can do this ?

```
TableView
{
model: someModel
TableViewColumn{title:"Time";role: "timeToReply";width: 170}
    rowDelegate: Item {
                clip: true
                Text {
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    color: {
                        if(timeToReply>15)             //problem
                        {
                            color="red"
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            color="black"
                        }
                    }
                    text: styleData.value
                    elide: Text.ElideMiddle
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: There is no QML TreeView in Qt yet. Also, what's column=time?